# Why does an oscillating charge emulate an oscillating dipole in the far field limit?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, quantum-electrodynamics, dipole

I understand Thomson scattering as: When an EM wave is incident upon a charge causes it to oscillate in turn releasing energy as another electromagnetic wave.

In an Electrodynamics lecture we took a different approach by assuming the far-field limit. The EM wave makes the charge oscillate causing it to emulate an oscillating dipole and hence releasing energy as another electromagnetic wave.

I understand that these two present the same behaviour in the far field limit. However, I do not intuitively understand how the oscillating charge emulates an oscillating dipole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a plane, electromagnetic wave is incident upon a charge, then if the motion of the charge is non-relativistic ($v \ll c$), the magnetic component fo the Lorentz force can be ignored and the charge accelerates with a sinusoidal dependence in the polarisation direction of the incoming electromagnetic wave. i.e.
$$m\ddot{r} = qE_0 \sin \omega t\ . $$
Integrating twice and assigning appropriate boundary conditions, this leads to displacement of the form $r = r_0 \sin \omega t$ and the electric dipole moment is just $q r_0 \sin \omega t$. i.e. An oscillating electric dipole moment.

An equivalent way of thinking about it is as a current oscillating backwards and forwards with $I = I_0 \sin \omega t$.

Answer (score 1):

If you do a multipole expansion of the field due to a charge displaced slightly from the origin I think you'll find it is equal to the field of a charge AT the origin plus a component due to a small dipole (whose magnitude is oscillating) at the origin. There are probably also negligible higher order quadrapole, octopole, etc. contributes.